# Some kind of fly, identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: Fly]

It has a really interesting shape. Is this a common fly ?

**Edit:** I found this in a relative's house. For area, I can say the  plateaus and mountainous parts of Turkey's mediterranean coast. I just saw a single one of them. It was alive. The size was like 1 cm. Never saw one before in my life. It peaked my interest so I decided to ask.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. We will need (1) the location, (2) the type of habitat, (3) a scale (how big was that approximatively). Also, was it alive? Did you see only one of them?

Comment: It seems to be an mayfly (*Ephemeroptera*) and not a fly (*Diptera*) as it looks like it has tail cerci. If it is one, then chances are you saw multiple of them all slowly dying.

Comment: @Remi.b I edited the question for more information.

Answer (score 3):

It is some sort of plume moth, *Pterophoridae*. I can't tell what species it is, but at least you know more about where to look! Or, hopefully, someone who knows more shows up.

There are probably better places to look, but I found [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moths_of_Turkey#Pterophoridae) of plume moths in Turkey on Wikipedia if you want to compare.

Comment: The funny thing is, if you google "t shaped fly" you can find images of this insect. :D

Comment: Yes, it's very handy when animals are easy to describe! Seems like a common species is even called "T-moth" in English.

Comment: It's funny, I just saw my first one ever tonight in Newfoundland, Canada. That family seems to have a wide distribution.